# One hot encoding a column with 28 different countires with only 6 classes

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a dataset in which a column 'Country' has 28 distinct countries. I need to first 'label encode' the column and then 'one hot encode' it with 6 labels only : top 5 most frequent countries : USA ,CHINA ,JAPAN ,FRANCE , CANADA and 6th label being 'OTHERS' for any other countries in the column

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where`:

```
countries = ['USA', 'CHINA', 'JAPAN', 'FRANCE', 'CANADA']
df['country_cat'] = np.where(df['country'].isin(countries), 
                             df['country'], 'OTHER')

# and then you can use `pd.get_dummies`
pd.get_dummies(df['country_cat'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simple solution using `lambda`. The `if elif else` conditions in `lambda` can even help you categorize it further!

```
top = ['USA', 'CHINA', 'JAPAN', 'FRANCE', 'CANADA']
df['country'] = df['country'].apply(lambda x : 'OTHERS' if x not in top else x)
pd.get_dummies(df['country'])
```

Comment: Can it also be done using one hot encoding procedure which can be imported from sklearn?